# How to mimic typing behavior in input field jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a component when the user types inside the text field, a type ahead appears i.e. data from the server that contains the user input. I want to test this behavior. So when the user types in "*some data*", I want to mimic that behavior in my react test class but now sure how to do.

---

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (inputValue) {
      if (inputValue.length > 2) {
        getTypeahead();
      }
    }
}, [inputValue]);

const getTypeahead = () => {
    service
      .getData(inputValue)
      .then((response) => {
        const slicedData = response.data.slice(0, 10);
        if (inputValue.toLowerCase().includes('some data')) {
          slicedData.push({name: 'test something'});
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
};


<FormField>
    <input value = {inputValue || ''} data-testid="test-id" />
</FormField>
```

---

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

jest.mock("../../service/Service", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => ({
    getData: async () => ({
      data: { name : 'test' },
    }),
  }),
}));

describe('Testing...', () => {
  test('Testing...', async () => {
    render(<Typeahead />);
    const input = screen.getByTestId('test-id');
    fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: 'something 2'}})
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `userEvent` which you have imported. User Events will typically fire multiple events. For example, `userEvent.type()` will handle focusing the input element, firing keyboard events and manipulating the selection and value fields of the input element as the "user" types.

```
describe('Testing...', () => {
  test('Testing...', async () => {
    render(<Typeahead />);
    const input = screen.getByTestId('test-id');
    userEvent.type(input, 'something 2')
  });
});
```